# Representing a line so it can be affine transformed

Tags: matrix, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader, linear-algebra

How do I represent a line, in a way that lets me efficiently translate it and rotate it about a point, and determine the distance from it?

This is all on a 2D plane.

This is my (abridged) fragment shader to calculate the distance from a line:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform mat3 u_transform;
void main() {
    vec3 line = vec3(2.0,1.0,-20.0)/sqrt(2.0*2.0+1.0*1.0);
    // line = u_transform * line; // doesn't work as intended
    float dist = dot(line, vec3(gl_FragCoord.xy, 1.0));
}
```

The affine transformation matrix doesn't correctly transform the line. How can I represent it, in a way that lets me efficiently perform the distance calculation, so I can affine transform it?

Comment: Efficientl operations on lines you say: How about [Plücker Coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_coordinates)?